# unable to install pod while using latest version of flutter 3.10.6

Tags: flutter, xcode, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

Even i'm using latest package and latest flutter version still it show this same error even i clean and run the project again
The error occurs due to a version mismatch in Firebase SDK components. The required Firebase/CoreOnly version 10.12.0 conflicts with the current firebase_core plugin version 2.15.0. Resolving the issue involves updating CocoaPods, checking Podfile for correct versions, and adding Firebase spec repo if necessary.
The error occurs due to a version mismatch in Firebase SDK components. The required Firebase/CoreOnly version 10.12.0 conflicts with the current firebase_core plugin version 2.15.0. Resolving the issue involves updating CocoaPods, checking Podfile for correct versions, and adding Firebase spec repo if necessary.
The error occurs due to a version mismatch in Firebase SDK components. The required Firebase/CoreOnly version 10.12.0 conflicts with the current firebase_core plugin version 2.15.0. Resolving the issue involves updating CocoaPods, checking Podfile for correct versions, and adding Firebase spec repo if necessary.

```
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.12.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.12.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 2.15.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.12.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.12.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

**Install pod in flutter project**